# Importing dictionaries in python

Tags: python

So I have looked at the answer to my question but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Basically, I am making a text based game and in one file I have a dictionary containing weapons that the character can collect but when I try to import the dictionary it says it cannot import that name. Here is a section of my code:

dictionary file:

```
import random
import sci_fi_rp

weapons_stash_c = {
    "pistols":{
        "basic_repeater":{
            "name": "Basic Repeater",
            "dmg": random.randint(6,9),
                    "ammo": 12,
                    "max_ammo": 12,
                    "level": hero.lvl
                },

        "laser_pistol":{
            "name": "Laser Pistol",
            "dmg": random.randint(8,11),
                    "ammo": 8,
                    "max_ammo": 8,
                    "level": hero.lvl
                },                  
   "laser_blaster":{
            "name": "Laser Blaster",
                    "dmg" : random.randint(10,12),
                    "ammo": 7,
                    "max_ammo": 7,
                    "level": hero.lvl
                    },
```

The game file:

```
import random
import time
from sci_fi_rp_weapons import weapons_stash_c

#Equipped weapon
laser_blaster = weapons_stash_c["pistols"]["laser_blaster"]
weapon_equipped = laser_blaster
```

I really don't know what has happened, they are in the same directory. I may have made a clumsy error I don't know, I have tried to check. Thanks!

Comment: Didnt you forget about `__init__.py` somewhere?

Comment: Can you add the exact error thrown to you?

Comment: I assume that by `"dmg": random.randint(6,9)` you want that either the weapon does a random amount of damage with each shot, or each instance of that weapon does a slightly different damage. However, the expression is evaluated only once, so each shot of each weapon of that type will deal the same damage, which is randomly determined once when starting the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests with your code and the problem seems to be the actual dictionary itself

Filename: sci_fi_rp.py << this has the dictionary

Filname: game.py

```
import sci_fi_rp << you put sci_fi_rp_weapons which isn't a file
print(sci_fi_rp.weapons_stash_c) << this returns a dictionary error
```

So the problem is filenames I think and then there is a dictionary error too

Try re-reading dictionary file the error kept getting was (SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing)